# PayPal - switching from Sandbox to Live account using REST API

Tags: api, rest, paypal

We tested our web application successfully using a sandbox REST API account (and test credentials). 
When we wanted to put the application into production (using REST API live credentials visible on the same PayPal web site where the sandbox/text credentials were shown), we received an error from the production PayPal server on a live credit-card transaciton:

Error code : 401 with response : Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

We have a Business Account that is not yet 100% verified (75% verified at the moment), so we are not sure if this is caused by some technical issue or the fact that the account is not yet 100% verified.

PayPal web site is quite confusing and the process of moving the app from test to production is not clearly explained. It seems that they are migrating from some old web sites to new ones and the user is prompted to login multiple times, redirected to different URL-s... E.g. we can see our application test and live credentials on the developer.paypal.com, but not on apps.paypal.com where no apps are listed, even though the same user is logged in (owner of the business account)???

Comment: can you provide the debug_id you get in the 401 error response? 401 usually occurs when there is something wrong with the access token you've passed in the Authorization header. Please make sure you are obtaining the access token using live credentials from live token endpoint.

Comment: This might help.https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, you have to use Live Credentials, on https://developer.paypal.com go to My apps and in App details there is a link at a bottom of the page :

[image]

Click on that link and you will see live credentials.

Comment: I hate PayPal for such attitude. I've missed the ***** link and spent 15 mins for googling such stupid thing, and creating API Access on the main site, which has turned out to be Classic API credentials. And than again googling.

Answer (score 2):

You now click on your sandbox application and then click live at the top of the screen to get your live credentials.

[image: Sandbox live toggle]

Answer (score 1):

For the PayPal REST api use the credentials provided on developer.paypal.com (new version of PayPal dev experience).  Live calls require the account to be vetted which includes fully verified.